# Property 'XXX' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I code as a hobby and I'm working on building a React website with TypeScript. I found a free Material UI template, and I'm trying to integrate it into the existing code. The template was written in JavaScript, and I'm having issues trying to get them to play nice.

This is my existing *login.tsx* file that I'm working with:

```
import { useState } from "react";

// react-router-dom components
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// @mui material components
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import Switch from "@mui/material/Switch";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import MuiLink from "@mui/material/Link";

// @mui icons
import FacebookIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Facebook";
import GitHubIcon from "@mui/icons-material/GitHub";
import GoogleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Google";

// Material Kit 2 React components
import MKBox from "../newcomponents/MKBox/";
import MKTypography from "../newcomponents/MKTypography";
import MKInput from "../newcomponents/MKInput";
import MKButton from "../newcomponents/MKButton";

import SimpleFooter from "../examples/Footers/SimpleFooter";

// Images
import bgImage from "assets/images/bg-sign-in-basic.jpeg";
import linearGradient from "assets/theme/functions/linearGradient";

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleSetRememberMe = () => setRememberMe(!rememberMe);


  return (
    <>
      <MKBox
        position="absolute"
        top={0}
        left={0}
        zIndex={1}
        width="100%"
        minHeight="100vh"
        sx={{
          backgroundImage: ({
            functions: { linearGradient, rgba },
            palette: { gradients },
          }) =>
            `${linearGradient(
              rgba(gradients.dark.main, 0.6),
              rgba(gradients.dark.state, 0.6)
            )}, url(${bgImage})`,
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundPosition: "center",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        }}
      />
      <MKBox px={1} width="100%" height="100vh" mx="auto" position="relative" zIndex={2}>
        <Grid container spacing={1} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" height="100%">
          <Grid item xs={11} sm={9} md={5} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Card>
              <MKBox
                variant="gradient"
                bgColor="info"
                borderRadius="lg"
                coloredShadow="info"
                mx={2}
                mt={-3}
                p={2}
                mb={1}
                textAlign="center"
              >
                <MKTypography variant="h4" fontWeight="medium" color="white" mt={1}>
                  Sign in
                </MKTypography>
                <Grid container spacing={3} justifyContent="center" sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 2 }}>
                  <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <MKTypography component={MuiLink} href="#" variant="body1" color="white">
                      <FacebookIcon color="inherit" />
                    </MKTypography>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <MKTypography component={MuiLink} href="#" variant="body1" color="white">
                      <GitHubIcon color="inherit" />
                    </MKTypography>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <MKTypography component={MuiLink} href="#" variant="body1" color="white">
                      <GoogleIcon color="inherit" />
                    </MKTypography>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </MKBox>
              <MKBox pt={4} pb={3} px={3}>
                <MKBox component="form" role="form">
                  <MKBox mb={2}>
                    <MKInput type="email" label="Email" fullWidth />
                  </MKBox>
                  <MKBox mb={2}>
                    <MKInput type="password" label="Password" fullWidth />
                  </MKBox>
                  <MKBox display="flex" alignItems="center" ml={-1}>
                    <Switch checked={rememberMe} onChange={handleSetRememberMe} />
                    <MKTypography
                      variant="button"
                      fontWeight="regular"
                      color="text"
                      onClick={handleSetRememberMe}
                      sx={{ cursor: "pointer", userSelect: "none", ml: -1 }}
                    >
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;Remember me
                    </MKTypography>
                  </MKBox>
                  <MKBox mt={4} mb={1}>
                    <MKButton variant="gradient" color="info" fullWidth>
                      sign in
                    </MKButton>
                  </MKBox>
                  <MKBox mt={3} mb={1} textAlign="center">
                    <MKTypography variant="button" color="text">
                      Don&apos;t have an account?{" "}
                      <MKTypography
                        component={Link}
                        to="/authentication/sign-up/cover"
                        variant="button"
                        color="info"
                        fontWeight="medium"
                        textGradient
                      >
                        Sign up
                      </MKTypography>
                    </MKTypography>
                  </MKBox>
                </MKBox>
              </MKBox>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </MKBox>
      {/* <MKBox width="100%" position="absolute" zIndex={2} bottom="1.625rem">
        <SimpleFooter light />
      </MKBox> */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

This is the *.js* file it is importing. I haven't made any changes to this.

```
/**
=========================================================
* Material Kit 2 React - v2.1.0
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-kit-react
* Copyright 2023 Creative Tim (https://www.creative-tim.com)

Coded by www.creative-tim.com

 =========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*/

import { forwardRef } from "react";

// prop-types is a library for typechecking of props
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// Custom styles for MKBox
import MKBoxRoot from "./MKBoxRoot";

const MKBox = forwardRef(
  ({ variant, bgColor, color, opacity, borderRadius, shadow, coloredShadow, ...rest }, ref) => (
    <MKBoxRoot
      {...rest}
      ref={ref}
      ownerState={{ variant, bgColor, color, opacity, borderRadius, shadow, coloredShadow }}
    />
  )
);

// Setting default values for the props of MKBox
MKBox.defaultProps = {
  variant: "contained",
  bgColor: "transparent",
  color: "dark",
  opacity: 1,
  borderRadius: "none",
  shadow: "none",
  coloredShadow: "none",
};

// Type checking props for the MKBox
MKBox.propTypes = {
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf(["contained", "gradient"]),
  bgColor: PropTypes.string,
  color: PropTypes.string,
  opacity: PropTypes.number,
  borderRadius: PropTypes.string,
  shadow: PropTypes.string,
  coloredShadow: PropTypes.oneOf([
    "primary",
    "secondary",
    "info",
    "success",
    "warning",
    "error",
    "light",
    "dark",
    "none",
  ]),
};

export default MKBox;
```

And this is the *.js* file that is imported from there:

```
/**
=========================================================
* Material Kit 2 React - v2.1.0
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-kit-react
* Copyright 2023 Creative Tim (https://www.creative-tim.com)

Coded by www.creative-tim.com

 =========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*/

// @mui material components
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default styled(Box)(({ theme, ownerState }) => {
  const { palette, functions, borders, boxShadows } = theme;
  const { variant, bgColor, color, opacity, borderRadius, shadow, coloredShadow } = ownerState;

  const { gradients, grey, white } = palette;
  const { linearGradient } = functions;
  const { borderRadius: radius } = borders;
  const { colored } = boxShadows;

  const greyColors = {
    "grey-100": grey[100],
    "grey-200": grey[200],
    "grey-300": grey[300],
    "grey-400": grey[400],
    "grey-500": grey[500],
    "grey-600": grey[600],
    "grey-700": grey[700],
    "grey-800": grey[800],
    "grey-900": grey[900],
  };

  const validGradients = [
    "primary",
    "secondary",
    "info",
    "success",
    "warning",
    "error",
    "dark",
    "light",
  ];

  const validColors = [
    "transparent",
    "white",
    "black",
    "primary",
    "secondary",
    "info",
    "success",
    "warning",
    "error",
    "light",
    "dark",
    "text",
    "grey-100",
    "grey-200",
    "grey-300",
    "grey-400",
    "grey-500",
    "grey-600",
    "grey-700",
    "grey-800",
    "grey-900",
  ];

  const validBorderRadius = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "xxl", "section"];
  const validBoxShadows = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "xxl", "inset"];

  // background value
  let backgroundValue = bgColor;

  if (variant === "gradient") {
    backgroundValue = validGradients.find((el) => el === bgColor)
      ? linearGradient(gradients[bgColor].main, gradients[bgColor].state)
      : white.main;
  } else if (validColors.find((el) => el === bgColor)) {
    backgroundValue = palette[bgColor] ? palette[bgColor].main : greyColors[bgColor];
  } else {
    backgroundValue = bgColor;
  }

  // color value
  let colorValue = color;

  if (validColors.find((el) => el === color)) {
    colorValue = palette[color] ? palette[color].main : greyColors[color];
  }

  // borderRadius value
  let borderRadiusValue = borderRadius;

  if (validBorderRadius.find((el) => el === borderRadius)) {
    borderRadiusValue = radius[borderRadius];
  }

  // boxShadow value
  let boxShadowValue = "none";

  if (validBoxShadows.find((el) => el === shadow)) {
    boxShadowValue = boxShadows[shadow];
  } else if (coloredShadow) {
    boxShadowValue = colored[coloredShadow] ? colored[coloredShadow] : "none";
  }

  return {
    opacity,
    background: backgroundValue,
    color: colorValue,
    borderRadius: borderRadiusValue,
    boxShadow: boxShadowValue,
  };
});
```

As is, the *login.tsx* file throws these errors and I'm having trouble working through them.

```
Type '{ position: string; top: number; left: number; zIndex: number; width: string; minHeight: string; sx: { backgroundImage: ({ functions: { linearGradient, rgba }, palette: { gradients }, }: { functions: { linearGradient: any; rgba: any; }; palette: { gradients: any; }; }) => string; backgroundSize: string; backgroundPo...' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.
  Property 'position' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'
```

```
Type '{ children: Element; px: number; width: string; height: string; mx: string; position: string; zIndex: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'
```

```
Binding element 'linearGradient' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

I think it's something to do with the ...rest operator, but messing around with it hasn't yielded a result.

The *login.tsx* file shows the errors:

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/2qzf9z

Comment: "Property 'position' does not exist on type" This means that the props of `MKBox` do not have a `position` prop. Why do you think it should have that prop?

Comment: According to the docs, it should accept all MUI props as well. https://www.creative-tim.com/learning-lab/react/box/material-kit/

Comment: Well without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this will be hard to solve. If you can [edit] your question with a link to, say, [a typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) that shows the type errors, that would help a lot.

Comment: I edited it to add a link to the sandbox

Comment: This is hardly [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It must be possible to reduce it by at least a factor of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! You're right that the `...rest` operator is part of the issue. What's happening is:

1. The `MKBox` component from the `.js` file doesn't indicate what type its props must be
2. TypeScript defaults to only knowing about the property names it can see: `variant`, `bgColor`, ..., `shadow`, `coloredShadow`
3. The `Login` component is trying to pass a `position` prop
4. That `position` prop isn't in that known list of property names, so TypeScript reports that it doesn't exist

The right solution would be to tell TypeScript what type `MKBox`'s props should be. See https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forward_and_create_ref for a good reference on how to use `forwardRef` in TypeScript in files you author:

```
import { forwardRef, ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
  children?: ReactNode;
  type: "submit" | "button";
}
export type Ref = HTMLButtonElement;

export const FancyButton = forwardRef<Ref, Props>((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="MyClassName" type={props.type}>
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

For files you aren't authoring, see if they have [`.d.ts` declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html), such as in a `@types/*` package on npm or bundled with them. If they don't have a `.d.ts` file you can pull in then you may need to file an issue on them asking for one... and in the meantime [write the type declarations yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).